# Creating a date index for data restructure

Tags: dataset, spss

I've got a dataset like in the example below (with thousands of rows for each participant):

```
participant-ID    date            duration
-------------------------------------------
id-1              01.01.2020      35
id-1              01.01.2020      15
id-1              01.01.2020      3
id-1              02.01.2020      120
id-1              02.01.2020      5
id-2              20.01.2020      13
id-2              20.01.2020      10
id-2              21.01.2020      450
id-2              21.01.2020      1
```

Some explanation of the data: For each participant we've collected data for several weeks everyday (with different start and ending dates for each participant) measuring the duration time of how long they've used their smartphones.

**First**, I would like to restructure such that the duration sum is calculated for each participant and each individual date (day 1, day 2, ...). It should look like that:

```
participant-ID    date            day          duration_sum
-----------------------------------------------------------
id-1              01.01.2020      1             53
id-1              02.01.2020      2             125
id-2              20.01.2020      1             23
id-2              21.01.2020      2             451
```

**Second**, I would like to create another restructured dataset, such that I've got one row for each participant and the duration time sums for each individual day (day 1, day 2, day 3, ...). The dates are irrelevant in this case.

```
participant-ID       duration_sum_day1       duration_sum_day2     ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
id-1                 53                      125                   ...
id-2                 23                      451                   ...
```

I'm thankful for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs a few steps. First I will recreate your example data to demonstrate on:

```
data list list/ID (a10)   date  (edate10)   duration (f6).
begin data
id-1              01.01.2020      35
id-1              01.01.2020      15
id-1              01.01.2020      3
id-1              02.01.2020      120
id-1              02.01.2020      5
id-2              20.01.2020      13
id-2              20.01.2020      10
id-2              21.01.2020      450
id-2              21.01.2020      1
end data.
```

Now to work:

```
* first step: summing durations per day (per ID).
dataset declare aggdata.
aggregate out=aggdata /break ID date /durationSum=sum(duration).
dataset activate aggdata.

* second step - creating a day index.
aggregate out=* mode=add /break ID/fstDay=min(date).
compute day=datediff(date, fstDay, "days")+1.
format day(f).

third step - restructure.
casestovars /id=ID /index=day /sep="_"/drop date.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-) I've had some trouble figuring out why this code didn't work for my original dataset. The problem was that first I had to convert the date (which was originally a string variable) into a date variable. When I changed it with the date and time wizard and pasted this into the syntax, your code didn't work ... only renamed the "duration" into "durationSum" in step 2 but did not add anything. When I changed the "date" into a date variable in the variable list, it worked for some reason. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: The date and time wizard code: 
`COMPUTE date=number(dateString, YMDHMS19).
VARIABLE LABELS date 'measuring date'.
VARIABLE LEVEL  date (SCALE).
FORMATS date (EDATE10).
VARIABLE WIDTH  date(10).
EXECUTE.`

Comment: My guess is this command failed (there must have been warnings, no?) because your dates are not in YMDHMS19 format. And then the rest of the code failed too of course. Try this instead: `COMPUTE date=number(dateString, edate10).`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to answer: but thanks, that solved it! :-)